# Text wrapping in numbered list

Tags: html, css, list, listview, styling

I have a styled numbered list but text is wrapping under the number. 
How can I fix it. 
I have numbers styled using CSS. I tried using different padding and margins, nothing works.

[image: screen shot]

```css
 ol.numbered-list {
  counter-reset:item; 
    margin-left:20; 
    padding-left:0; 
}
ol>li {
    counter-increment:item; 
    list-style:none inside; 
    margin: 30px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
ol>li:before {
    content:counter(item) ;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 45px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #01A7E5;
    color: #01A7E5;
    text-align: center; 
    font: 20px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numbered-list">
    <li><strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Invoice Number</span></strong></li>
    <li><strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Service Address:</span></strong> The address where you receive Entrust Energy electricity service.</li>
    <li><strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Account Number:</span></strong> Your Account Number identifies each Entrust Energy account you may have and is often used to pay your electric bill or set up recurring payments. You may have more than one Account
        Number.
    </li>
    <li><strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Bill Date: </span></strong>The date your electric bill is processed. You will receive one electric bill per month.</li>
    <li><strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Account Summary:</span></strong> An itemization of your balance, payments
        <g class="gr_ gr_18 gr-alert gr_gramm gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim Punctuation only-ins replaceWithoutSep" data-gr-id="18" id="18">and</g> charges for electric service as disclosed in your electricity facts label (EFL), including applicable taxes and fees. Please refer to the EFL you received when you signed up with Entrust Energy for more information about your applicable
        electric bill rates.</li>
    <li><strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Total Amount Due:</span> </strong>This is the total amount that you currently owe Entrust Energy, including past due balances from your previous electric bills. When paying your electric bill by mail, please do
        so at least five days prior to the due date so that we receive your bill on time. Click here to learn about your other payment options.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? I have removed the `float:left` from your `:before` tag - as this usually removes the item from the usual layout.

In order to make the `:before` and your content align on one line - I've wrapped your text in a `<p>` tag and used `display:flex` on the list items (`li`).

```css
ol.numbered-list {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol>li {
  counter-increment: item;
  margin: 15px 0;
  display: flex;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(item);
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  min-width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #01A7E5;
  color: #01A7E5;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="numbered-list">
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Invoice Number</span></strong>
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Service Address:</span></strong> The address where you receive Entrust Energy electricity service.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Account Number:</span></strong> Your Account Number identifies each Entrust Energy account you may have and is often used to pay your electric bill or set up recurring payments. You may have more than one Account
      Number.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Bill Date: </span></strong>The date your electric bill is processed. You will receive one electric bill per month.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Account Summary:</span></strong> An itemization of your balance, payments
      <g class="gr_ gr_18 gr-alert gr_gramm gr_inline_cards gr_run_anim Punctuation only-ins replaceWithoutSep" data-gr-id="18" id="18">and</g> charges for electric service as disclosed in your electricity facts label (EFL), including applicable taxes and fees. Please refer to the EFL you received when you signed up with Entrust Energy for more information about your applicable
      electric bill rates.
    </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>
      <strong><span style="color:#01A7E5;">Total Amount Due:</span> </strong>This is the total amount that you currently owe Entrust Energy, including past due balances from your previous electric bills. When paying your electric bill by mail, please
      do so at least five days prior to the due date so that we receive your bill on time. Click here to learn about your other payment options.
    </p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Oh, it is working in the code snippet within my answer - can you see that one working? Did you copy the whole code I've given here (including the HTML)? What's not working for you?